# Timer Going too fast after first quiz Swift 3

Tags: swift

i have quiz app and have 10 sec timer each question. First question timer is fine, but in second question it going faster than before. I try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sJQoofU7-0) tutorial to make timer and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyxqsfrCaeM) tutorial to make quiz app

here's my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
timerBegin()
}

func timerBegin() {
    myTimer.invalidate() // print error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
    timeLeft = 10
    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SoalViewController.timerRunning), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timerRunning() {
    timeLeft -= 1
    timeLabel.text = "\(timeLeft)"
    if timeLeft == 0 {
        myTimer.invalidate()
        timeLabel.text = "10"
        pickQuestion()
        timerBegin()
    }
}
```

here's my option button code :

```
@IBAction func opsiA(_ sender: Any) {
    timeLabel.text = "10"
    timerBegin()
    if AnswerNumber == 0 {
        pickQuestion()
        Score += 10
        scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    } else {

        pickQuestion()
        print("Wrong")
    }
}
@IBAction func opsiB(_ sender: Any) {
    timeLabel.text = "10"
    timerBegin()
    if AnswerNumber == 1 {
        pickQuestion()
        Score += 10
        scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    } else {
        pickQuestion()
        print("Wrong")
    }
}
@IBAction func opsiC(_ sender: Any) {
    timeLabel.text = "10"
    timerBegin()
    if AnswerNumber == 2 {
        pickQuestion()
        Score += 10
        scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    } else {
        pickQuestion()
        print("Wrong")
    }
}
@IBAction func opsiD(_ sender: Any) {
    timeLabel.text = "10"
    timerBegin()
    if AnswerNumber == 3 {
        pickQuestion()
        Score += 10
        scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    } else {
        pickQuestion()
        print("Wrong")
    }
}
```

and this is my pick question function :

```
func pickQuestion() {
    if Questions.count > 10 {

        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10)))
        textView.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
        AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer
        for i in 0..<Buttons.count {
            Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)
    } else {
        darkView.isHidden = false
        scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
        timeLabel.isHidden = true
        if Score > standStill {
            HighScore = Score
            highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Highscore : %i", HighScore) as String
            let currentHighScore = UserDefaults.standard
            currentHighScore.set(HighScore, forKey: "HighScore")
        } else {
            let currentHighScore = UserDefaults.standard
            currentHighScore.set(standStill, forKey: "HighScore")
        }
    }

}
```

i already try to stop timer by adding `myTimer.invalidate()` in first line of timerBegin function but it print `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Use `myTimer?.invalidate()`. Don' use implicitly unwrapped optionals if you can avoid it (`Timer?` instead of `Timer!`).

Comment: So is this a question about the timer going too quickly? Or is this a question about the crash because you are unwrapping an optional that is nil?

Comment: You need to boild this down to an MWE. Nobody wants to read all the GUI code if the problem is in the backend.

Comment: because of timer run too fast ,  try to use following line    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

Comment: Right, i change myTimer: Timer? and it works, thanks @Sulthan